# In Fortran can I rely in reading tabs-delimited ascii files with list-directed "read"

Tags: fortran

Is it Fortran-standard compliant to read a tabs-delimited Ascii file like this one:

```
    0.11 0.12 0.45
```

(where the space is actually a tab) with list-directed input like this:

```
    read(11,*) real1,real2,real3
```

Comment: Closely related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29383838/read-and-write-tab-delimited-text-data

Comment: Certain, compilers treat a tab as a blank, but you are asking for the standard.

Comment: Yep, It works with intel fortran compiler under windows. I wanted to know if this is portable.

Answer (score 2):

A more interesting question than a first glance might suggest ...

The standard stipulates that `blanks` are to be recognised as *value separators* for list-directed input.  In Table 3.1 'Special Characters' of (my version of the draft of) the standard a space is denoted `Blank character`, but there is no further explanation or definition of `blank`.  So a space is definitely a `blank` *inside the source of a Fortran program*.

It is well known (??) that the tab character is not part of the Fortran character set, and some compilers will, by default, object to its presence in source files (outside character variable contexts).  But I can't see any anyone writing a compiler that would fail to recognise a tab character as a blank for list-directed input of a list of numbers.

I think the answer to the question is

> Whether or not a tab character is a value separator for an input list
>   is processor dependent (i.e. it's left up to the compiler writer) so the standard doesn't stipulate that you can absolutely rely on this behaviour.

but I'll be interested to see what the language lawyers have to contribute on this one.

Comment: Intel treats tab as a blank for sure.

Comment: "Additional characters may be representable in the processor, but may appear only in ... input/output records" may be the part you are after.

Comment: @francescalus: yes, that would be the part I missed !  Editing my answer.